How to cache instantly in React Tanstack Query?
Problem:
I'm using TanStack Query (formerly React Query) to fetch and display course data in my app. I have three categories of courses:

My Courses (i.e., courses the user owns, shown as ownedCourses)

Available Courses (courses available for purchase)

Unavailable Courses


When I load the page and fetch the data, only available courses are displayed. However, my courses (owned courses) do not appear immediately. After pressing F5 (refreshing the page), the "My Courses" section is empty until I navigate between subpages in the app. Once I do that, the courses load correctly.
What I Expected:
I expected the useQuery to refetch or update the data instantly, showing all course categories without needing to switch pages. I thought configuring staleTime would resolve the issue by controlling when the cache is considered "stale," but it hasn’t worked as expected.
What I Tried:

I set different staleTime values (such as 1000ms) to control caching behavior, but it didn't make a difference.

I also enabled refetchOnWindowFocus to force refetching, but it still doesn’t display my courses instantly after refreshing.
const { data, error, isLoading, refetch } = useQuery<CourseDataResponse>({
  queryKey: ['courseData'],
  queryFn: async () => {
    const { data } = await AXIOS.get<CourseDataResponse>(
      '/api/courses/courses?page=1&sort[orderId]=asc'
    );
    return data;
  },
  staleTime: 1000, // Tried different values here
  refetchOnWindowFocus: true,
});

const courses = data?._embedded.items ?? [];

const ownedCourses = authState
  ? courses.filter((course: CourseItem) => course.accessible)
  : [];

const purchaseAvailableCourses = courses.filter(
  (course: CourseItem) => course.available && !course.accessible
);

const unavailableCourses = courses.filter(
  (course: CourseItem) => !course.available
);


Question:
How can I ensure that the "My Courses" data (owned courses) displays immediately after refreshing the page without needing to navigate away and back? Am I missing any configuration in TanStack Query to make the cache update or refetch immediately?


